# Is it OK to submit an answer to a question that you, yourself, have asked?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

I have a particular question that may be useful to the community, but I already know a possible answer.

Am I able (allowed) to submit an answer to my own question?

I'd hope that anybody would be able to submit an answer, including myself.

Comment: Yes, but give others a chance to answer it first.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not only useful for the original question asker, but for *everyone else who has the same problem* and finds the question later (could be thousands of people for some questions). If you had a tough question for SE but already found a good answer, and think there's a chance one or more people other people could use it, please ask it on the appropriate SE site. That's why Joel and Jeff encourage it so much. Nothing wrong with being the first answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that is OK, in podcasts Jeff and Joel even used to encurage it, so go ahead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to check the trilogy sites for this. Accepted answer as this was the quickest.

Comment: Not only that, but there's a badge you can get for having an answer on your own question upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

It's not only OK, it is encouraged, if you have a good answer.

There's a similar discussion on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions), take a look.

Comment: +1 for you, I'm having a read now.