# Would a question asking for making a website's text content distraction/clutter free be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I have a self-answerable question wherein I want to share how an article on Medium.com can be read without any clutter at the top, bottom, and in the sides. I wrote a userscript for removing bells and whistles.

Userscripts are on-topic, but the premise of the question I am unsure of, because what counts as clutter free could be deemed personal or opinionated.

I have sought [suggestion on network's meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360936/286110) as to where this question would be on-topic but I have not gotten anywhere with that yet.

Would my question be on-topic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about **using** a web application as [medium](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medium) are on-topic on this site, just be sure that your question follow the guidelines of [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answers that suggest the use a userscript might be well received, just be sure that your answer follows the guidelines of [How do I write a good answer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Related

- [Is it OK to ask and answer my own question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4019/88163)